# A problem with spaces basis and generator system

Tags: linear-algebra

I solved a problem where a basis for a set of vectors S of R^4 for a subspace W = gen S is required. The problem is that I find three vectors only that would be the basis because of being L.I and generator, using the following statement:

> Let V = Rm, and S = {v1, v2, . . . , vn} a set of non-zero vectors in V. The procedure for determining a subset of S that is a basis for W = gen S is the next:
> Step 1. Form equation (3),
> c1v1 + c2v2 + · · · + cnvn = 0.
> Step 2. Build the augmented matrix associated with the homogeneous system resulting from equation (3), and take it to the reduced row echelon form.
> Step 3. The vectors in S corresponding to the columns containing the main entries (1s) form a basis for W = gen S

So after finding the basis, it should meet both of the conditions, but I see something's wrong with this. Hence I would appreciate someone could check the problem and tell why is the supposed base not being a generator, maybe because the problem is wrong. Thank you.

[First Part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmlIy.jpg)

[Second Part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ne1eE.jpg)

[Basis proof attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5A2n.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The zero row means one of the vectors was linearly dependent on the other three. So the span of those four vectors is only three dimensional. It's a proper subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField so you are saying that the problem's solution is correct, right? Quite didn't understand your explanation about the span of those four vectors. Could you please explain me more about it? Thank you so much.

Comment: @dendroaspispolylepis I didn't check your work I just noticed the zero row and assumed you calculated it correctly. For a simpler example consider the span of $(1,0)$ and $(2,0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Even though it's two different vectors we have $2\cdot (1,0)=(2,0)$. This means they only span a one dimensional space, namely the $x$-axis.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I verified my work a couple times and it's correct. The fact was that I wasn't getting the reason why the last row was a zero row, as it would be disqualifying for a generator system, but you have made it easier to understand. Thank you, Sir.